Are all random variables estimators?
My hand-wavey understanding is a random variable is a function from a domain of possible outcomes in a sample space to a measurable space valued in real numbers.
We might denote a random variable from a distribution to a real value then as $X$, using capital letters to denote its status as a random variable.
My understanding of an estimator is that it is a function, say, $g$, of a random variable used to calculate some quantity of interest.
Can we not then simply say that all random variables are estimators, then, given that they can also be functions that estimate the quantities they represent? For example, $X$ can be thought of as an identity estimator of its estimate realisiation, $x$.
Not sure that really makes sense but I'm hoping the replies help me better better understand the differences. I have seen $X$ described as an estimator, which surprised me, and I am not sure what to make of it.

This is not a duplicate question..

Asserting it is not does not help us understand how it is not or explain why we might want to reopen it.  Could you please let us know what aspect(s) of your question are not answered in the duplicated thread?

@whuber They ask different questions.
One asks about the inclusivity of a definition: Are all RV's in some sense estimators?
Another is focused on the why of things: Why is an estimator considered a random variable?

I think the duplicate answers the second question.  It does not address the first one--that comes down to a matter of definition that isn't discussed there--so if you would edit your post to focus on that I think it would be appropriate here on CV.

FWIW you define yourself random variable and estimator as different functions, performing mapping between at least three different spaces:

domain of possible outcomes
a sample space to a measurable space valued in real numbers
some quantities of interest

So logically random variable and estimator defined this way map between different pairs of spaces and are not the same thing. They can be often sloppily designated by the same letter (say $x$), but this means different things depending on the context.
